# Best practices for multiple Redis instances on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm planning on adding a second Redis instance to my Rails application. From reading the docs, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#establish-the-primary-instance, the best practice for doing this on Heroku seems to be to designate one of the instances as the "primary" instance, point to it with the `REDIS_URL` config var, and have another config var with some other name pointing to the second instance.

This doesn't quite suit me, since I have more semantic names I'd like to use.

How important is it to designate one of my instances as "primary"? What do I get by doing so? The docs contain sentences like 'Heroku recommends using the `REDIS_URL` config var to store the location of the primary instance' but don't go into further detail.

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @knagode Good to know someone is reading this! Yes, and I posted it below.

Comment: Hehe. Thanks for  answering. Helpful stuff!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing magic about `REDIS_URL`. Quoth support:

> While Heroku recommends to establish a single data store service as a primary and some tools are built around this convention, it is surely possible to have more than one data services with other config var names.
>
> To specify a semantic name for the config var, please add an --as option to the addon:create command like so:
>
> ```
> heroku addons:create heroku-redis --as PERSISTENT_REDIS -a my-heroku-app
> ```
>
> Moreover, an existing add-on can be attached through a different config var like below. Please refer to the output from the heroku addons command to see what is the add-on name (redis-abc-1234 in the example below) to be used.
>
> ```
> heroku addons:attach redis-abc-1234 --as VOLATILE_REDIS -a my-heroku-app
> ```